# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_array() in */tt_functions.php on line 118

Tags: php, sql

Okay so, I'm just trying to alter a piece of work produced by "diafol" over at DaniWeb, which he said was just a quick look at how PHP could build an interactive timetable, to get to grips with how I could produce a similar product for my own project...

Seemed good until...

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysql_array() in /home/*/*/TimeTable/tt_functions.php on line 118
```

Here is the section it is referring to....

```
$rs = mysql_query("SELECT id, firstname, surname FROM users ORDER BY surname, firstname");
while($data = mysql_array($rs)){
    $user_id = $data['id'];
    if($chkusr != '' && in_array($user_id,$chkusr)){
        $user_checked = ' checked = "checked"';
    }else{
        $user_checked = "";
    } 
    $username = stripslashes(html_entity_decode($data['firstname'])) . " " . stripslashes(html_entity_decode($data['surname']));
    $output .= "\n\t\t<input type='checkbox' id='user{$user_id}' value='{$user_id}' name='checkuser[]'{$user_checked} /><label for='user{$user_id}'>{$username}</label>";
}
```

Comment: it is mysql_fetch_array, not mysql_array

Comment: y are you using mysql ..its been deprecated .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such .. `mysql_array()`it must be [`mysql_fetch_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php)

Rewrite your code like ...

```
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
```

---

Sidenote : The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would be something simple I'd missed! I'll approve it as an answer as soon as the site lets me.

Answer (score 0):

use `mysql_fetch_array` or `mysql_fetch_assoc` in given line

```
while($data = mysql_array($rs)){
```

modify it by

```
 while($data = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
```

**Note:**

`mysql_*` is deprecated use `mysqli_*` or `PDO`